# Making layer names in legend permanent using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, legend, layer-name

While constructing a legend in Print Layout, I modify the names of the layers just in the legend, but not in the Layers panel (works as expected). Reproducible code is at bottom.

However, after I close the project (after saving layout and project) and reopen it, **the modified layer names in the legend returns to original state**. See pictures below:

Before closing the project (layer name in legend is 'Layer A'; in Layers panel is 'new layer'):

[image]

After reopening the project (layer name in legend is back to 'new layer'; 'should' have continued 'Layer A'):

[image]

How can I make the modified layer names in legend sticky/permanent?

---

Reproducible code:

```py
import os
from qgis.core import *
from qgis import processing
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

#Current .qgz folder
dir = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./") + '/'

#Path to output folder
path_output = os.path.join(dir,'output')

#Create 'output' folder, if it does not exist
if not os.path.exists(path_output):
    os.makedirs(path_output)

#Create sample layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temporary_points", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
vl.startEditing()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("name", QVariant.String)])
fet = QgsFeature()
fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(15,60)) )
fet.setAttributes(["Johny"])
pr.addFeatures([fet])
vl.commitChanges()

#Reproject and save new layer in 'output' folder
params = {'INPUT':vl,\
          'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),\
          'OUTPUT': f'{path_output}/point_layer.gpkg'}
result = processing.run('qgis:reprojectlayer', params)

#Add reprojected layer
reprojected_layer = QgsVectorLayer(result["OUTPUT"], "new_layer", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(reprojected_layer)

#Print Layout
layers_list = list(QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values())

project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout_name = "test"
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName(layout_name)
manager.addLayout(layout)
iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout)

map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map.setId('map_1')
map.setRect(20, 20, 20, 20)
rect = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
map.setExtent(rect)
map.setFrameEnabled(True)
map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(297, 210, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
layout.addLayoutItem(map)

legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setLinkedMap(map)
legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True)
legend.setId('legend')
legend.setTitle("Legend")
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)

layers_to_add = {}

for layer in layers_list:
    if layer.name() == 'new_layer':
        layers_to_add[layer] = 'Layer A'

#add more layers
#for layer in layers_list:
#    if layer.name() == 'layer_B':
#        layers_to_add[layer] = 'Layer B'

root = QgsLayerTree()
for i, (layer, legend_text) in enumerate(layers_to_add.items()):
    tree_layer = root.addLayer(layer)
    tree_layer.setUseLayerName(False)
    tree_layer.setName(legend_text)    
legend.model().setRootGroup(root)

legend.setStyleFont(QgsLegendStyle.Title, QFont('MS Shell Dlg 2', 13))
legend.setStyleFont(QgsLegendStyle.Subgroup, QFont('MS Shell Dlg 2', 13))
legend.setStyleFont(QgsLegendStyle.SymbolLabel, QFont('MS Shell Dlg 2', 12))
legend.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255,255,255,0))
legend.adjustBoxSize()
legend.setFrameEnabled(True)
legend.setFrameStrokeWidth(QgsLayoutMeasurement(0.3))

legend.updateLegend()
layout.addLayoutItem(legend)

project.write()
```